# Mongoose collection statistics / manipulations queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

- first, a comment. The collection described is simplified, for this question. I'm interesting in understanding how to manipulate a mongo db and get statistics of my data.

Let's say I have a collection with test results. The schema is:

```
Results {
  _id: ObjectId
  TestNumber: int
  result: String     // this contains "pass" or "fail"

  // additional data
}
```

For each test can be many reports, so most likely each `TestNumber` appears in more than one document.

How can I perform a query which returns this info on the entire collection:

```
TestNumber | count of result == "pass" | count of result == "fail"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below aggregation operations pipelined together:

- `Group` all the documents based on their `testNumber` and the type of
  `result` together, so for every testNumber, we would have `two`
  groups each, one for `fail` and another for `pass`, with the count of
  documents in each group.
- `Project` a variable "pass" for the group containing the result as
  pass, and fail for the other group.
- `Group` together the documents again based on the testNumber, and
  push the pass and fail documents into an array.
- `Project` the fields as required.

The Code:

```
Results.aggregate([
{$group:{"_id":{"testNumber":"$testNumber","result":"$result"},
                "count":{$sum:1}}},
{$project:{"_id":0,
           "testNumber":"$_id.testNumber",
           "result":{$cond:[{$eq:["$_id.result","pass"]},
                            {"pass":"$count"},
                            {"fail":"$count"}]}}},
{$group:{"_id":"$testNumber",
         "result":{$push:"$result"}}},
{$project:{"testNumber":"$_id","result":1,"_id":0}}
],function(a,b){
// post process
})
```

Sample Data:

```
db.collection.insert([
{
"_id":1,
"testNumber":1,
"result":"pass"
},
{
"_id":2,
"testNumber":1,
"result":"pass"
},
{
"_id":3,
"testNumber":1,
"result":"fail"
},
{
"_id":4,
"testNumber":2,
"result":"pass"
}])
```

Sample o/p:

```
{ "result" : [ { "pass" : 1 } ], "testNumber" : 2 }
{ "result" : [ { "fail" : 1 }, { "pass" : 2 } ], "testNumber" : 1 }
```

iterating `doc.result` will give you the pass count and the number of failed tests for the `testNumber`.